# How to *automatically* test CSS rendering in different browsers (included Safari Mobile and Android Browser)?

Tags: css, selenium, testing, bdd

I'd like to know if there's programmatic, automatic, BDD-aware way to test how CSS is rendered in different browsers, just like Selenium can automatically test HTML and Javascript in different browsers. Integrating it with a BDD framework would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

You can see it in different browsers with:

[browsershots](http://browsershots.org/)

Comment: 1. I mean *automatically* | 2. Browsershots has no safari mobile | 3. Browsershots has no android browser

Comment: @Leonardo Dario Perna: I have never seen such tool but hope someone knows *probably* :)

Answer (score 0):

Try Needle: http://needle.readthedocs.org/

It works with Selenium. Runs in capture mode to grab screenshots of the site, then re-runs in test mode to compare the output to the screenshot.